# Django - Is this possible that the add default values when model is creating?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I want to add some default values in my database when the related model is creating with makemigrations command.

For example I have this as model;

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created Date')
      modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Update Date')
      is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Deleted')

      class Meta:
          abstract = True

class ModelType(BaseModel):
      description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=225 )
```

and as I said before I want to add some default values ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4") for my ModelType table. Is that possible?

Comment: Use fixtures in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I tried that and it is work correctly for me but I have one more question. Am I always load data from django shell or migrations is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always add the default data when you execute a given migration, the safest way is to use a datamigration (as suggested by @Kos).

To create a data migration, use `./manage.py makemigrations <app_label> --empty` and manually add the required code to populate the data.

I normally use a custom operation which executes a get_or_create on the specified model. Add this code to either the migration file itself or somewhere where it can be imported from:

```
from django.db import migrations


def noop(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


class EnsureInstanceCreated(migrations.RunPython):
    def __init__(self, app_name, model_name, attrs, defaults=None):
        super(EnsureInstanceCreated, self).__init__(self.add_instance, noop)
        self.app_name = app_name
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.attrs = attrs
        self.defaults = defaults

    def add_instance(self, apps, schema_editor):
        Model = apps.get_model(self.app_name, self.model_name)
        Model.objects.get_or_create(
            defaults=self.defaults,
            **self.attrs
        )
```

Then, in the migration itself:

```
from django.db import migrations
from myproject.utils.migrations import EnsureInstanceCreated


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myproject', '000x_auto_...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        EnsureInstanceCreated('myapp', 'ModelType', attrs={
            'description': 'value1',
        }, defaults={
            # ...
        }),
        EnsureInstanceCreated('myapp', 'ModelType', attrs={'description': 'value2'}),
        EnsureInstanceCreated('myapp', 'ModelType', {'description': 'value3'}),
    ]
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer and sample codes. I did what you said and it is work me for just one time. I delete those values after adding and make migrations again and this time it did not work. What am I suppose to do for work these codes for every migrations command?

Comment: Django migration system works with an history. See table "django_migrations" in your DB. Once you've applied a migration, it will not be reapplied until you delete the corresponding line in "django_migrations" table. If you deleted manually your data from the table corresponding to your model, those data will ne be re-added later. If you need this behavior, you may register your data with fixtures instead of data migrations

Comment: @bullception, as a Antwane said, the django migrations system is one-off. However, if you are in need to reapply a given migration a second time, you can migrate --fake back to the migration before the data migration, then migrate forwards by one and fake again a forward migration till the top. (if you find yourself in need to apply the same migration multiple times, then a fixture is more appropriate).

Comment: thanks for your help guys. I have solve the problem with using fixtures. In my docker settings file I also specify the **./manage.py loaddata myfixtures.json** command and this is work for me correctly all the time that I build my project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a way. You can use Fixtures to initialize models with data.

Refer to this piece of documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Data migrations can add data to DB tables.

Comment: I am not very sure as to how, you can initialize models with data via migrations. But you can surely dump data with Fixtures.